# Require help on Java EE infrastructure choosing the right "mix"

Tags: java, soa

I am a bit lost nowadays with all the available libraries out there. What I'd like to have is a small app server (best: jboss as7 as it is very lightweight and based on osgi) and have a lightweight, yet efficient soa-like infrastructure. I was looking on apache service mix though it looks quite complicated/complex. What I basically want to have is this:

- Easy definition of stateless services (easy as in a simple java pojo class)
- Modularization with automatic service discovery using osgi
- Services can automatically represent themselves as either WebService OR (!!) JSON-Format like REST Service
- Integrated, easy to handle authentication using OpenId to secure any service endpoint including handling all validation/verification processes

I couldn't easily figure which of all frameworks would really fit in, for example, in Apache Service Mix I can't seem to find support to represent services as JSON-like RESET services nor could I find any integration of security?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want GlassFish 3.1 to me. I can't speak to JBoss or any of the other Java EE 6 containers.

Java EE 6 pretty much covers most of your requirements:

- Easy definition of stateless services -- that's a Stateless Session
  EJB, and that's just a Pojo -- put @Stateless at the top if it.
- Services can automatically represent themselves as a WebService --
  that's also a Stateless EJB -- put @WebService at the top of it.
- Integrated, easy to handled authentication using OpenId -- JSR 196 (Java Authentication SPI for Containers) covers that, but you'll need an implementation specifically for Open ID. Oh, apparently [here](http://www-02.imixs.com/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/openid_serverauthmodule_jsr_196_with) is one.

That's all just plain 'ol Java EE 6.

For OSGi, GlassFish 3.1 is a full boat OSGi platform and all of the EJBs are also OSGi discoverable. So I guess you get that for free as well.

As for HTTP JSON WebServices, JAX-RS will do that, but not "for free" like @WebService can. But creating a facade of HTTP RPC on top of a Session Bean should be trivial, since JAXB in Jersey (the JAX-RS implementation within GlassFish) will publish Java as JSON or XML.

So, I'd start there with GF 3.1 and bend it until it breaks rather than running around the net playing ala carte.